# The joint probability density function of $X$ and $Y$ is given by $f(x,y) = e^{-(x+y)}$, for $x > 0, y > 0$. Then $P(X = Y) =$?

Tags: density-function, joint-distribution

I'm a little confused as to what $P(X=Y)$ means here. I'm not quite sure what are the steps I'm supposed to take.

Comment: It refers to the probability that X =Y. If the probability is not immediately clear, it might help to think in terms of P(X-Y=k), and consider what values of X-Y are possible.

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us 
what you understand thus far, what you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll 
provide hints to help you get unstuck.

Comment: @WaldirLeoncio, please don't add the `[self-study]` tag for the OP. Ask them to add it themselves & to read its wiki. That way there is a better chance they will be familiar w/ our policies. If they don't add the tag, we can close the question.

Comment: @gung, agreed..